# Set Library security roles through the Graph API in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm terribly sorry if this has been answered before, but I could not find anything by searching. I'm trying to [add users to a library role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/about-security-roles?view=azure-devops#library-asset-security-roles-variable-groups-and-secure-files) though the Azure DevOps API, however I'm struggling to find the correct endpoint to do this. I'm fairly certain the Graph API needs to be used.

What would be the correct endpoint to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Set Library security roles through the Graph API in Azure DevOps

For this issue , you can try this api:

```
PUT https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/securityroles/scopes/distributedtask.library/roleassignments/resources/{resourceId}?api-version=5.1-preview
```

Sample request body:

```
[{
    "userId": "123b6558-85d0-464f-b2a7-xxxxx",
    "roleName": "Creator"
}]
```

Sample response :

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "value": [
        {
            "identity": {
                "displayName": "[111]\\Contributors",
                "id": "123b6558-85d0-464f-b2a7-xxxxx",
                "uniqueName": "[111]\\Contributors"
            },
            "role": {
                "displayName": "Creator",
                "name": "Creator",
                "allowPermissions": 5,
                "denyPermissions": 0,
                "identifier": "distributedtask.library.Creator",
                "description": "Creator can create and view the library items.",
                "scope": "distributedtask.library"
            },
            "access": "assigned",
            "accessDisplayName": "Assigned"
        }
    ]
}
```

This api was fetched from the Network by pressing `F12` in the browser.

[image]

In addition, on how to add a user as a project group member, you can refer to this [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#examples).